# Options lifecycle in ASP.NET Core dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

Which lifetime cycle has the configuration object got when it's registered the following way?
Is it a singleton, transient or scoped?

```
  {
      services.Configure<SomeConfiguration>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(SomeConfiguration)));
  }
```

This is how I get the configuration into my service class

```
public class SomeService: ISomeService
{
    public SomeService(IOptionsMonitor<SomeConfiguration> configuration)
    {
         _configuration = configuration.CurrentValue;
    }
}
```

Its is very to hard know from debugging it if its a singleton or not. Because IOptionsMonitor is able to detect changes on run time by running a watcher on appsettings.json changed

Answer (score 10):

**IOptions**

- Is registered as a [Singleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#singleton) and can be injected into any [service
  lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes).

**IOptionsSnapshot:**

- Is useful in scenarios where options should be recomputed on every
  request.
- Is registered as [Scoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#scopedhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#scoped) and therefore cannot be injected into a
  [Singleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#singleton) service.

**IOptionsMonitor:**

- Is used to retrieve options and manage options notifications for
  TOptions instances.
- Is registered as a [Singleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#singleton) and can be injected into any [service
  lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes).

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 2):

As per the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1#options-interfaces):

The `IOptionsMonitor<TOptions>`

> Is registered as a Singleton and can be injected into any service lifetime.

You can also check out the github code for the `OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs` to see how the dependencies are registered - [REF](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as you said, from your ref,  line 72 show clearly that is a singleton